# Eclipse doesn't show parameter names for macro expansion

Tags: c, eclipse, gmp, code-completion

I'm currently developing a program which makes use of the GNU Multiple Precision library (GMP) and I'd like to be coding in Eclipse. I have created a new makefile project and I'm using the Makefile just fine, however, I don't get Eclipse to show the arguments (atleast the types) for the functions in the GMP library. I have already included the correct include directions where the library is located, and it finds every reference just fine.

[image]

However, when I want to use a function, like `mpz_add()` it gives me the icon for a macro (which is also okay)

[image]

But it doesn't give me autocomplete on the parameter types of this function. When I use the `Open Declaration (F3)` context menu entry, I get the correct macro-expansion

[image]

Where you can see that this function takes the args `mpz_ptr, mpz_srcptr, mpz_srcptr`, but these don't show up when I write something in the function (open a parenthesis, type a comma, do a `Ctrl+Space`)

[image]

Any idea on why it can't give the parameter types? I really don't like to open the manual for every function I call to look up what parameter types they use :/.

Edit: I'm using the most recent Eclipse, "Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)", the C/C++ developer version.

Edit2: It does however give me autocomplete on the macro-expanded version.
[image]

Comment: The macro itself does not take arguments. It is hard for an IDE to guess that it should expand the macro and complete based on that. If you want this to be improved, posting to the eclipse bug tracker would be more productive.